# Am not able to find the Redirect and is not working in react app

Tags: reactjs, redux

Redirect is not working in my react-router-dom; when am trying to import and use redirect in the app - I am getting the following error when running npm run start in the terminal. - Attempted import error: 'Redirect' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

```html
 import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

    const PrivateRoute = ({ ...rest }) => {
      const { auth } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));

      return auth && auth.token ? <Route {...rest} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
    };

    export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

So the new react-router-dom version 6 does not have Redirect as an exported member. But there is one similar component that you case use that is Navigate:

import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ ...rest }) => {
  const { auth } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));

  return auth && auth.token ? <Route {...rest} /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace={true} />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

you can read more about that: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/navigate

I have created similar Protected Route component that you can use:

Protected Route:

```
const PrivateRoutes = ({ component: Component }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { auth } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!(auth && auth.token) ) {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, [auth]);

  if (auth && auth.token) {
    return <>{Component}</>;
  }
  return <></>;
};

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

Then you can use this like this:

```
 <Route
    path="/contacts"
    key="AllContacts"
    element={<PrivateRoute component={<AllContacts />} />}
  />
```

Comment: here us the error message when am trying to use the navigate. - Uncaught Error: [PrivateRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Comment: Thank you but its not working

Comment: can you please elaborate what issue are you facing?